# How to put derivative in terms of derived function

Tags: derivatives

The question asks to find $f’(2)$ when $f(x)=h(x^2-3)$.

I tried solving using the product rule and got $f’(x)=h(2x)+h’(x^2-3)$. I substituted $2$ for $x$ and got $4h+13h’$. But the answers are all in terms of $h’$ and no $h$.

How do we change $h$ into $h’$ in the situation above? I tried finding $h$ in terms of $f(x)$ using algebra but it doesn’t make it easier.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you use the product rule for a composition???

Comment: $h(x^2-3)\ne h\times (x^2-3)$

Comment: @5201314 so that’s where it went wrong!